# list of nullable bool values is always nulls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view. In my partial a few properties are nullable boolean. If I check or uncheck the checkbox it is always null when I save the this record. What should I do if I want it to return  false when check to uncheck and true when uncheck to check, otherwise null?

Here is the Entity class:

```
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DocType { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "User")]
    [Required]
    public int Key { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Path")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool? ShowFullWidth { get; set; }
    public List<DmFormDefDTO> DmFormDefItems { get; set; }
    public bool? IsEnabled { get; set; }
```

Here is my partial view:

```
  if (Model.DmFormDefItems != null)
        {
<div class="main-body">
    <div id="container-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="ordertable">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Enabled
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DmFormDefItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr class="OrderDetailRow">
                        <td>
                            @if (Model.DmFormDefItems.ElementAt(i).ShowFullWidth == true)
                            {
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DmFormDefItems[i].ShowFullWidth.HasValue) <label>Show Full Width Page</label>    
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DmFormDefItems[i].ShowFullWidth.HasValue) <label>Show Full Width Page</label>                                            
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (Model.DmFormDefItems.ElementAt(i).IsEnabled == true)
                            {
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DmFormDefItems[i].IsEnabled.HasValue)     
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DmFormDefItems[i].IsEnabled.HasValue)        
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>              
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

the checkbox can only have a true or false state. when handling bool? i use a dropdown list (NULL / True / False)

```
public static class BooleanDropdownListForHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString BooleanDropdownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> property)
    {
        return BooleanDropdownListFor(htmlHelper, property, null);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString BooleanDropdownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> property, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(property, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        bool? value = null;

        if (metadata != null && metadata.Model != null)
        {
            if (metadata.Model is bool)
                value = (bool)metadata.Model;
            else if (metadata.Model.GetType() == typeof(bool?))
                value = (bool?)metadata.Model;
        }

        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem() { Text = BooleanTypeFor.Yes, Value = "True", Selected = (value.HasValue && value.Value == true) },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = BooleanTypeFor.No, Value = "False", Selected = (value.HasValue && value.Value == false) }
        };

        return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(property, items, htmlAttributes ?? new { });
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont want to use any dropdown

Comment: Three radio buttons also work (Edit: Or two radio buttons where the user has some mechanism for unselecting both)

Comment: Tristate checkbox is possible (like it exist in WPF) with few code. See some projects like http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/02/02/three-state-checkbox-in-asp-net/ or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20159/ASP-NET-TriState-CheckBox-Made-Easy

Comment: MVC already has a this built in. `@Html.EditorFor()` used with `Nullable<bool>` produces a drop down with `True`, `False` and `Not set`. The only difference is the MVC helper does it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you not binding to your boolean property, your binding to its `HasValue` property which is a readonly property of `Nullable<T>` ([refer documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx)) which means it cannot be set when you post back, so the value in your controller will always be the default `null` value.

A checkbox only has 2 states (`true` or `false`) but a `Nullable<bool>` has 3 states (`true` or `false` or `null`) so there is no way a `Nullable<bool>` can be represented using a checkbox input.

3 possible options

1. Use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.yourNullableBool)` which will generate a
   dropdown with 3 values ("True", "False" and "Not Set")
2. Use 3 radio buttons bound to your `Nullable<bool>` property with the values
   `true`, `false` and `null`
3. Develop you own html helper and jquery plugin