# How to pass the Checkbox Checked or Not to Controller from View in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 with razor view and I want to pass the Checkboxfor's Checked or Not value to Controller's create method from Create View but in the post method I am getting null value in **m_category.IsActive** so can anyone help me to solve my problem ,My Create view as per given below

```
@model Test.Models.M_Category
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Category"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    ....
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryName, "Category Name")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CategoryName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive, "Is Active")
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive.Value, new { @class = "checkbox" })                                    
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive)
    </div>
    ....
}
```

and my create controller method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(M_Category m_category)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

             M_Category obj = new M_Category();
            obj = db.M_Category.Where(x => x.CategoryName.ToLower() == m_category.CategoryName && x.CategoryID!=m_category.CategoryID && x.IsDeleted == false).FirstOrDefault();
            if (obj == null)
            {
                obj = new M_Category();
                obj = db.M_Category.Find(m_category.CategoryID);
                obj.IsActive = m_category.IsActive;//here I am getting null value
                obj.CategoryName = m_category.CategoryName;
                db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        TempData["exists"] = "record already exists.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you mean the `IsActive` property? Your view shows that you have commented out the checkbox for the `IsActive` property And is you getting `null`, then that means its `bool?` (show your model!) and you cannot use a checkbox for a nullable `bool`

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke thanks,  I have edit the code it was not commented ....and yes I want to use the IsActive property ...

Comment: As per previous comment, you **cannot** bind a `nullable bool` to a checkbox. (look at the name attribute of the checkbox and its associated hidden input to understand)

Comment: so what is the other way for the same?  have any idea ?

Comment: Use `EditorFor(m => m.IsActive)` - it will generate a dropdownlist with `true/false/null` or change the property to `bool` (a checkbox has 2 states, but a nullable bool has 3 states)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list of nullable bool values is always nulls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749499/list-of-nullable-bool-values-is-always-nulls)

Comment: Sorry  but not understand your last point.may you explain me please

Comment: A nullable bool has 3 states (it's value can be `true`, `false` or `null`) but a checkbox has only 2 states (`on` or `off`) therefore you cannot use a checkbox to bind to a nullable bool